# EntityFramework StoredProcedure recuperar parametro output

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures

Como recuperar o parametro Output de uma storedProcedure?

SP Exemplo:

```
create PROCEDURE StoreProcedure_Name 
    @ParametterWithNummvalue    varchar(50) = null, 
    @In_Parameter varchar(50), 
    @Out_Parameter varchar(10) out
AS

    set @Out_Parameter = 'teste'

RETURN 0
```

Código C#

```
SqlParameter[] Params = {
                new SqlParameter("@ParametterWithNummvalue", DBNull.Value),
                new SqlParameter("@In_Parameter", "teste novo"),
                new SqlParameter("@Out_Parameter", SqlDbType.VarChar, 10) { Direction = ParameterDirection.Output }};

            var r = Db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("exec StoreProcedure_Name @ParametterWithNummvalue, @In_Parameter, @Out_Parameter", Params);

            var ReturnValue = Params[2].Value;
```

ReturnValue deveria conter o valor "teste" mas está retornando vazio.

Comment: O que realmente você que retornar?  uma String o int?

Comment: @MarconcilioSouza desculpe, escrevi errado não é int é varchar

Answer (score 1):

Olá, tente fazer da seguinte maneira:

```
//Separe os parâmetros de entrada e saída
var parametterWithNummvalue = new SqlParameter();
parametterWithNummvalue.ParameterName = "@ParametterWithNummvalue";
parametterWithNummvalue.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
parametterWithNummvalue.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar;
parametterWithNummvalue.Size = 50;
parametterWithNummvalue.Value = null; //Substitua pelo valor desejado

var inParameter = new SqlParameter();
inParameter.ParameterName = "@InParameter";
inParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
inParameter.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar;
inParameter.Size = 50;
inParameter.Value = null; //Substitua pelo valor desejado

var outParameter = new SqlParameter();
outParameter.ParameterName = "@OutParameter";
outParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
outParameter.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar;
outParameter.Size = 10;
outParameter.Value = null; //Substitua pelo valor desejado

var valorRetornado = new SqlParameter();
valorRetornado.ParameterName = "@ValorRetornado";
valorRetornado.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int;
valorRetornado.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

//Chame a procedure com base nos parâmetros criados
var dados = Db.Database.SqlQuery("exec @ValorRetornado = StoreProcedure_Name @ParametterWithNummvalue, @InParameter, @OutParameter OUT", valorRetornado, parametterWithNummvalue, inParameter, outParameter);
```

**Obs:** *Perceba que da forma que sua procedure foi criada no exemplo, retornará dois valores, um no OUT (variável: outParameter) e outra no RETURN (variável: valorRetornado).*

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: ambas as variáveis (outParameter e valorRetornado) estão retornando null

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver apenas adicionado a expressão **Out** após o parametro **outParameter** (resposta do TomCunha)

No final ficou assim:

```
SqlParameter[] Params = {
    new SqlParameter("@ParametterWithNummvalue", DBNull.Value),
    new SqlParameter("@In_Parameter", "teste novo"),
    new SqlParameter("@Out_Parameter", SqlDbType.VarChar, 10) { Direction = ParameterDirection.Output }};

var r = Db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("exec StoreProcedure_Name @ParametterWithNummvalue, @In_Parameter, @Out_Parameter Out", Params);

var ReturnValue = Params[2].Value;
```